# Image rest of height inside a div-Container

Tags: html, css

I have got the following code:

HTML:

```
<div id="mapWrapper" style="height: 624px;">
    <div class="box" id="map">
        <h1>Campus</h1>
        <p>Description Campus Map.</p>
        <img src="abc.png">
    </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 3px;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:100%;
 }

#mapWrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px;
}

#map {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

#map img {
     height: 100%;
}
```

I want the image to take the rest of the height, that is free in the map-div. Currenty the image is set to 100% and that is why it runs out of the box at the bottom. Can someone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a `display:table` setup, the advantage of this is that you can add as much content as you want to the first 'row' and the image will take up the remaining space (whatever is left from the table height minus the first row of content) and scale accordingly.

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/MvTB6/5/)

HTML

```
<div class='table'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='cell'>
            <h1>Campus</h1>
            <p>Description Campus Map.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='cell'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.table {
    display:table;
    table-layout:fixed;
    height:624px;
    width:100%;
    max-height:624px;
}
.row {
    display:table-row;
}
.cell {
    display:table-cell;
}
.row:first-of-type >.cell {
    height:1%;
}
.row:last-of-type >.cell {
    height:100%;
    background-image:url(http://www.gettyimages.co.uk/CMS/StaticContent/1357941082241_new_banner-700x465.jpg);
    background-size:contain;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
}
```

Comment: The width of my map-div shall be calculated by the height, that is possible for the image.

Comment: This does not work for me. Can you give me a working example, where the image has not the full width of the outer container? i want the image width to be adjusted by its height.